# How to escape apostrope value

Tags: javascript, html, wso2, html-escape-characters

My code is like this

```
<%
var publicjirasummary = ex.getAttribute("jiraInformation_publicjirasummary");
var cleanDatapublicjirasummary = (publicjirasummary == null)? "" : publicjirasummary;
%>

<input type="text" id="publicjirasummary" name="publicjirasummary" class="round full-width-input" value='<% print(cleanDatapublicjirasummary);  %>'/>
```

This code works fine ,but the problem occurs when user enter string like follows
"Public Jira Summary field value can't displays"

Then results display only following part of the string

> "Public Jira Summary field value can"

Problem occurs only with " ' " mark.How to change code to escape " ' " this character in a comman way?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tryed with traditiona escape like:

```
\'
```

Comment: I changed my code as follows using str.replace("'","\'") .But still it is not working  <input type="text" id="publicjirasummary" name="publicjirasummary" class="round full-width-input" value='<% var publicjirasummary = (ex.getAttribute("jiraInformation_publicjirasummary")); var cleanDatapublicjirasummary = (publicjirasummary == null)? "" : publicjirasummary; print(cleanDatapublicjirasummary.replace("'", "\'"));  %>'/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "Public Jira Summary field value can't displays"
str = str.replace(/'/g, '');
```

The reason your version wasn't working is because str.replace returns the new string, without updating in place.